# .htaccess - add to the start of RewriteCond url

Tags: .htaccess

In my `.htaccess` I would like to check if a file exists in a certain folder, if so redirect there.

Let's say there comes in a request like so `http://example.com/image1.png`, I want to check if that file exists on the path `/view/image1.png` ifso, redirect there. So, the eventual redirect would look like `http://example.com/view/image1.png`, but only if the file exists there!

How my attempt at this looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/view/ -f
RewriteRule (.*) /view/$1 [L]
```

Clearly this is not correct as it's not working, but I can't seem to find the correct way to add to the *start* of the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have this RewriteCond and RewriteRule to check if the file exists in the folder view. If so, redirects to the file.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/view/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule (.*) /view/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I hate `.htaccess` so much, you're the savior of my sanity!